# Interaction of Color (albers) - book question

Tags: color, color-theory

Wasn't sure where else to ask this, but I have just finished The Interaction of Colors, which is an excellent book by a Bauhaus legend. I had one glaring issue which I wanted to bring up-- in one of the plates demonstrating the concept of colors influencing each other, the author asserts that the small squares in the below screengrab are exactly the same color.

*note* artifacting errors caused by sub par scanner, but I wanted to include a prop for show and tell.

[image: http://i207.photobucket.com/albums/bb289/teh_Mac/00_InteractionOfColor_PLvi-4_zps6ae27f40.png]

As you can see, even with the knowledge that colors can influence each other and present illusions, that it doesn't look like those squares are the same color.

I have read that later editions of this book (this particular edition is a later edition) suffered from reproduction errors, and this may be one such error. Does anyone have a picture of the original or some insight into what color the small squares actually would be?

Comment: I don't know the book in question but for those sorts of optical illusions, you normally need three colours with a mid colour that is somewhere between the other two. There are a few examples of the principle that this looks like it's supposed to illustrate in [this answer to another question "How to use poor colours well"](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13305/3327)

Comment: Are you able to quote the except of text?

Comment: @JohnB I could include a screengrab of the opposite page, but there's not much text, and it does not list the three colors presented, it just says there's three of them.